# Vaadin with Android- How to develop and Synch UI components with Vaading in Android

Tags: android, vaadin7, vaadin-touchkit

I am planning to develop an application with adding the UI components of Vaadin framework to the android development.

I need some suggestions and advices whether it is possible in android or not. If possible how exactly we can do that.

Looking for the reply . Thanks in advance

Regards
Anand